# in random module, I'm trying to get two numbers not one. what should I add?

Tags: python

```
import random

rand_int = random.randint(1, 21)

print(rand_int)
```

I have no idea what to add. :/
elementary level but still difficult for me!

Comment: you can try using sample
`random.sample(range(1, 21),2)`

Comment: If you want two random numbers, call `randint()` twice...

Answer (score 1):

You could try another call to randint:

```
import random

rand_int_a = random.randint(1, 21)
rand_int_b = random.randint(1, 21)

print(rand_int_a, rand_int_b)
```

Comment: this is awesome. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Here, this function should do the trick :

```
import random
def randomnumbers(n,rb,re): # n is the number of numbers, rb is range begining, re is range end
  returnlst = []
  iterationnum = 0 # number of iterations
  while iterationnum != n:
    returnlst += [random.randint(rb,re+1)]
  return returnlst
```

Comment: would be nicer if the 2 variables would be in one data structure. also it isn't clear from the questions if numbers can repeat.

Comment: I have edited my work, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`rand_list = [ random.randint(1,21) for i in range(n)]`

This will get you a list of random integers.

Comment: Chiko asked for two numbers and not a list, though this would work for two numbers, I don't necessarily think this is what Chiko wanted

Comment: We do not know the entire purpose of the Chiko's code. A list of random integers might be more efficient than having multiple variables which store the same.

Comment: Chiko just said she wanted two numbers, no more no less

Comment: @Theshape and who says that OPs can just order an answer to their likings? If we have 2 or more elements, a list is always an option.

Comment: I guess so... @vikingosegundo